# json array in php url

Tags: php, json

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost/datas.php?[{ id :27,latt:8.55699,ltd:76.882,tm:11:46:51}, { 
id :97,latt:8.55699,ltd:76.882,tm:11:46:52}, { id 
:31,latt:8.55699,ltd:76.882,tm:11:46:52}, { id 
:96,latt:8.55703,ltd:76.8815,tm:11:53:22}]
```

I need to enter all these values to database using php

I tried many ways.but no way, its not working.

So far I done this.

```
$response = array();
$response["data"] = $array;
$json = json_encode($response);
var_dump($json);
```

but it shows data null.

please help me to solve this

Comment: Never ever pass json array through url, very bad

Comment: also the format you need to use is:-`http://localhost/datas.php?data ='[{ id :27,latt:8.55699,ltd:76.882,tm:11:46:51}, { 
id :97,latt:8.55699,ltd:76.882,tm:11:46:52}, { id 
:31,latt:8.55699,ltd:76.882,tm:11:46:52}, { id 
:96,latt:8.55703,ltd:76.8815,tm:11:53:22}] '`

Comment: actually i got this url from an android app..how can i overcome this issue.

Comment: i formatted url like this. but its showing the same.

Comment: try: `$json = json_encode($_GET['data]; var_dump($json)`
and remove the rest of your posted php code

Comment: @user5060801 check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Never ever pass json through URL, you can convert it into string and then decode it as below :

test.php

```
<?php 
$json = '[{
    "id": 27,
    "latt": 8.55699,
    "ltd": 76.882,
    "tm": "11: 46: 51"
}, {
    "id": 97,
    "latt": 8.55699,
    "ltd": 76.882,
    "tm": "11: 46: 52"
}, {
    "id": 31,
    "latt": 8.55699,
    "ltd": 76.882,
    "tm": "11: 46: 52"
}, {
    "id": 96,
    "latt": 8.55703,
    "ltd": 76.8815,
    "tm": "11: 53: 22"
}]';
echo 'http://localhost/test.php?data='.base64_encode($json);
?>
```

test1.php

```
<?php 
$getdata = $_GET['data'];
$cjson = json_decode(base64_decode($getdata));
print_r($cjson);
?>
```

Result you get will be :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 27
            [latt] => 8.55699
            [ltd] => 76.882
            [tm] => 11: 46: 51
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 97
            [latt] => 8.55699
            [ltd] => 76.882
            [tm] => 11: 46: 52
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 31
            [latt] => 8.55699
            [ltd] => 76.882
            [tm] => 11: 46: 52
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 96
            [latt] => 8.55703
            [ltd] => 76.8815
            [tm] => 11: 53: 22
        )

)
```

**Also the json is not in correct format. Please use validated json.**

Comment: @user5060801 check above answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like below.

```
$json = file_get_contents('url_here');

$obj = json_decode($json);

echo $obj->access_token;
```

Comment: @sunil kumar, there is no need of file content read. OP asking for url not any file data !

Answer (score 0):

Atlast found solution for this.

```
$a = $_REQUEST['data'];
$bb = json_decode($a,true);
foreach ($bb as $res=>$value) {
$uid = $value["id"];
.
.
.
}
```